# Sampling GRanges object rows using probabilities

Tags: r, bioinformatics, sampling, bioconductor

I have the following object `variable1`:

```
GRanges object with 25605 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
              seqnames             ranges strand   |  totgenes   density
                 <Rle>          <IRanges>  <Rle>   | <integer> <numeric>
      [1]         chr1 [3000001, 3100000]      *   |         2       0.2
      [2]         chr1 [3100001, 3200000]      *   |         1       0.1
      [3]         chr1 [3200001, 3300000]      *   |         1       0.1
      [4]         chr1 [3300001, 3400000]      *   |         1       0.1
      [5]         chr1 [3400001, 3500000]      *   |         2       0.2
      ...          ...                ...    ... ...       ...       ...
  [25601] chrUn_random [1600001, 1700000]      *   |         0         0
  [25602] chrUn_random [1900001, 2000000]      *   |         0         0
  [25603] chrUn_random [2100001, 2200000]      *   |         0         0
  [25604] chrUn_random [2400001, 2500000]      *   |         0         0
  [25605] chrUn_random [5900001, 5900358]      *   |         0         0
```

and I want to take randomly 100 rows from this object. For that:

```
sample(variable1, 100)
```

However, I'd like to sample using `prob=` according to the density column. I can do this:

```
sample(sort(unique(variable1$density)), prob=table(sort(variable1$density))/25605, replace=TRUE, size=100)
```

but that way, I only get the density values. I'd like to get the whole rows.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your problem with a smaller data.frame?

Comment: have you had a look at the [pps-Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pps/pps.pdf)?

Comment: You're taking a sample of a vector of unique density values.

Comment: Not sure what weights you want to use, but looks like `sample(variable1,100,TRUE,prob=table(variable1$density)[factor(variable1$density)])` could be it.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
sam <- sample(variable1, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = variable1$density)
```

Metadata columns in GRanges objects (to the right of the line above) can be accessed using `$`, just as in a data frame.